# I want to play gif animation on touch event

Tags: android, animated-gif

```
package com.example.gifsample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

//@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView
            (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");

        setContentView(view); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

.

```
package com.example.gifsample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class GIFWebView extends WebView {
    public GIFWebView(Context context, String path) {
        super(context);
        loadUrl(path);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Now I want this to be played on touch event whenever I touch my screen and it should be stopped after its one loop is completed.
I don't want to play the animation again when the animation is already playing. The animation should complete the loop and then it can be played again on touch event.

Comment: If the `gif` itself is looping- you can't stop it, it's built inside of it.

Comment: No, the gif is being eddited by me. so it is only a single loop gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen to `MOTION_EVENTS` (`onTouch()` method) use this code and paste it into the `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    // You can also put any code here, it will be caught when you touch the screen
    break;
    // This event here is triggered when you lift your finger from the screen, when touching it
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

    GIFWebView view = new GIFWebView
        (this, "file:///android_asset/imageedit_ball.gif");

    setContentView(view);

    break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In case when your `gif` file is looping only once, it will be shown as so.

Because you're instantiating a class, which extends `WebView`. Those classes do not intercept `onTouch` events. Only `Activity` classes do.

Here's a nice tut about playing the gif files - [LINK](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/) and a nice project in the google.cod that you can use - [LINK](https://code.google.com/p/animated-gifs-in-android/).

Comment: But the problem with this is it occupies the entire screen with setcontentview(). How to convert this view in to imageview or imagebutton if possible making gif animation possible inside layout with all other stuff..

Comment: I have tried this code, but every time a new object of GIFView i.e. view is created. I have already created it at first.The gif is being played onload event but after that it get stopped and then on touch event it is not getting played again. I have even tried to create a global object of GIFView but I m unable to find the solution.

Comment: Yes, this is beacause you're instantiating a class, which extends `WebView`. Those classes do not intercept `onTouch` events. Only `Activity` classes do.

Comment: I edited the question, there are three (or more) methods to load the `gif` file: split it into frames and animate those, use `WebView` (your method here) and use it inside a `VideoView`. Only your method does not intercept touches on the screen when you open the file, because the class which handles it is extending `WebView`.